# Passport-azure-ad how to create Bearer token to pass to authentication

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, passport-azure-ad

I am working on an API that will have multiple client front ends.  While the OID Connection strategy is currently working, some of the interactions is from servers attaching to the API instead of clients (no user interaction).  I was looking into the Bearer Strategy, but can't figure out how to allow the server to authenticate.

Server A -- calls API on --> Server B via Bearer Strategy

Call must include Bearer Token.  Note:  Both Server A and Server B are written in Node.JS (not C#).  Answers should address Node.JS libraries.

Also, we would like to restrict by Active Directory Groups.  We are using on-premise Active Directory that is Synced to Azure AD via ADFS.  Thank you.

Comment: Well, I'm a C# guy mostly so I'll just try to give some pointers. Server to server calls are done with the client credentials flow in AAD. It is a good idea to at least one application permission in your API and assign that to the other app. The token it gets will then contain the app permissions given to it. You mention groups but those don't apply typically in Azure AD when talking about server to server authentication. You can add service principals to groups via PowerShell though. So maybe if you defined a user role and assigned the group to it.. But it sounds like an odd way.

Comment: I mention groups from the stand point of how we do it currently on premise using IIS (ASP.NET, CFML based applications).  IIS authentications, we then query AD for user groups on behalf of user to see what the cgi.auth_user is member of.  The Server A will know who the user is (at least login/username).  It is essence delegated authority.  Server A calls the API on Server B on behalf of authenticated user known to Server A.  The API needs to restrict by groups assigned to user (either directly known on Server B or passed on behalf of by Server A).

Comment: The main question is how to create the Bearer authentication from Server A to Server B.  Server A is trusted at Server B along with users directly access Server B.  In the case of Server A to Server B, the trust will be full (no role restrictions).  Server A will be responsible for restricting operations for its authenticated users.